# correctly referencing a case's thread in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, case, reference

External case links look like this for our company

companyname.force.com/s/case/weirdnumber

the peeps who setup Salesforce set that external email to send

companyname.force.com/s/case/{!relatedTo:CaseNumber}

well, that link does nothing, because "CaseNumber" should be the weird reference number (usually like 00500 something).

anyways, do you guys know what syntax I can use to make it refer to the correct number? maybe i can find a list of VisualForce !relatedTo: objects too? I'm not a VF developer so I don't know that much.

right now working off this to see if it resolves my issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AfHrIAK

Comment: change the semicolon to dot.. {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}

Answer (score 1):

The field I ended up needing was  {!relatedTo.Id}